# Converting Latitude and Longitude(double) data to byte array in order to store in mySql as Geometry or GeometryCollection value in java

Tags: java, mysql, latitude-longitude, type-conversion, spatial

My requirement is to store latitude and longitude coordinates(**Double** dataType values) fetched from a mobile webservice on **java server** and store in mySQL db as **Geometry** or **Geometry collection** datatype. I've created the table using one of the below queries:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`location`(    
`coords` GEOMETRYCOLLECTION);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`location`(
`coords` GEOMETRY);
```

And in **NetBeans** inside my project, I've created an entity to store values from webservice to the db. And when I've created the entity for the table in my db, the `coords` column from db is reverse engineered as `byte[]` in the entity(since the *geometry/geometrycollection* is a `blob` in db).

From the client device(lets say a mobile), I get the **latitude** and **longitude** as **Double** values from webService to my **java server** something like:

```
lati:  21.0826801  lng:  80.2707184
```

Now I need to convert those coordinate values which are **Double** to **byte[ ]**, such that it should look like a **spatial data** that is derived from one of the 3 queries below:

**Query Type 1:**

```
INSERT INTO location VALUES (geomfromwkb(point(9.197915773, 45.476819539)));
```

**Query Type 2:**

```
INSERT INTO location VALUES (geometrycollection(point(9.197915773, 45.476819539)));
```

**Query Type 3:**

```
INSERT INTO location VALUES (geomcollfromwkb(point(9.197915773, 45.476819539)));
```

How could I achieve it?
Sorry for the long post, I've searched all around the web including *stack overflow* and found nothing relevant to my current scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The first and third give you a "point", as seen via

```
mysql> select ASTEXT(geomfromwkb(point(9.197915773, 45.476819539)));
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| ASTEXT(geomfromwkb(point(9.197915773, 45.476819539))) |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| POINT(9.197915773 45.476819539)                       |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select ASTEXT(geometrycollection(point(9.197915773, 45.476819539)));
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| ASTEXT(geometrycollection(point(9.197915773, 45.476819539))) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(9.197915773 45.476819539))          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select ASTEXT(geomcollfromwkb(point(9.197915773, 45.476819539)));
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| ASTEXT(geomcollfromwkb(point(9.197915773, 45.476819539))) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| POINT(9.197915773 45.476819539)                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I see no need for `byte[]`.

Comment: But the entity converts the GEOMETRY or GEOMETRYCOLLECTION dataType of mySQL to `byte[]` since the geometry data is stored as a `blob` in mySQL. That's why I'm in need of it!